# Add element to doctrine ArrayCollection by Id

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I find very annoying to have to fetch an object by id from database every time I want to add it to a relationship. Is there a way to add an object to a a relationship by id instead of adding the whole object?

This is my actual code:

```
...
$person = $em->getRepository("Person")->findOneById($id);
$me->getPersons()->add($person);
...
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
...
$me->getPersons()->add($id);
...
```

Then I would be saving one trip to the database! Which I like better! Is it possible?

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? If you already know the ID of the person you want to add, that might imply that you have the person object previously loaded somewhere

Comment: The $id variable is a request parameter

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to do that actually. You can get reference object like so:

```
$person = $em->getReference("Person", $id);
$me->getPersons()->add($person);
```

Doctrine will not make a query for `Person` but will instead return an reference proxy object for person with that id. If you, however do:

```
$person = $em->getReference("Person", $id); // 0 queries
$person->getId(); // Still 0 queries
$person->getSomeField(); // query fired
```

Doctrine will trigger lazy load if you try to get some field that has to be fetched from database.

See docs[EntityManager::getReference method](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_getReference)